# firebase HTTP Cloud Function TimeOut?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm working on online booking android app project. It uses Firestore and Cloud Function.

In app Booking go through three phase

1. phase(Initiate Order) : I receive order request and hit `makeOrder()` http callable cloud function which create a document in bookings collection which has a field `status=
   "inProcess"` and it send response with `CHECKSUMHASH` (used to do payment later) to client.
2. phase(do payment): If first phase completed successfully now user have to do payment by using `CHECKSUMHASH` which is generated in first phase. If payment TXN successful then payment API ([more](https://developer.paytm.com/docs/v1/android-sdk)) also give `CHECKSUMHASH` in response. Now I have to verify 
   `CHECKSUMHASH` at server side  to ensure that request has not been tampered.
3. phase(Confirm Order):  At this stage `CHECKSUMHASH` (generate by Payment APT ) has to be verified, so i call another HTTP Cloud Function `confirmOrder()`. If method  `verifychecksum()` returns `true`, then I change status `"inProcess"` to `"pending"`.

**Now problem is that it always take more than 60sec so give error TimeOut.**

My Questions are

1. It is taking time bec i'm checking document exist or not just after creating it

   ```
   db.collection(targetColRef).doc(data.TARGET_ID).collection('orders').doc(data.ORDER_ID).get();
   const time = getCurrentDate().time;
   if (doc.exists && (time - doc.orderTime) < 300)
   ```
2. I am booking order by these three phase, Is it right way to do this?

   ```
   exports.confirmOrder = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
       if(validateData()){

            yield new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
                     return verifychecksum(data,paytm_config.MERCHANT_KEY);

                 }).then((result) => __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () {
                     if (result) {
                        const doc = yield db.collection(targetColRef).doc(data.TARGET_ID).collection('orders').doc(data.ORDER_ID).get();
                          const time = getCurrentDateNumber().time;
                          if (doc.exists && (time - doc.orderTime) < 300) {
                         yield db.collection(targetColRef).doc(data.TARGET_ID).collection('orders').doc(data.ORDER_ID).update({ status: 'pending' });
                         }
                         else { //doc not exists
                            console.log("Order not exist Or time diff more than 300 sec ! /DATA=>" + JSON.stringify(data) + "/Context=>" + JSON.stringify(context));
                             throw new functions.https.HttpsError('permission-denied', 'Time Out!');
                         }
                     }
                     else { // result==false
                         console.log("Failed to verify checksum! /DATA=>" + JSON.stringify(data) + "/Context=>" + JSON.stringify(context));
                         throw new functions.https.HttpsError('permission-denied', 'bad request');
                     }
                     //..
                 })).catch((err) => {
                     throw new functions.https.HttpsError('permission-denied', err);
                 });

                 console.log("successfull");

                 return "successfull";
    }else{
           //.... }})):
   ```

Comment: There's no need to apologize for your English, as it is perfectly understandable. But please use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to make your question look good.

Comment: Sure sir @Frankvanpuffelen

Answer (score 1):

The environment that your Cloud Functions execute in requires that you return either a value or a promise, so that it can reliably know when your function is done with its work.

If your Cloud Function times out after 60 seconds, it is *very* likely that you're not returning any result. In your case, I'm highly suspicious of the `function*` and:

```
yield new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
```

I don't see where you're completing the generator function. I'm quite sure `__awaiter` has something to do with it, but I'm also quite sure that it's not working for you.

I recommend refactoring the code to use simpler and more commonly used primitives, such as:

```
return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
```

If you have multiple promises that need to complete before the function is done, look at `Promise.all()`, which is much more common than generator functions.

I highly recommend checking out Doug's video on [promises in Cloud Functions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7IkUgCLr5oA).